# PHP - Relative Paths! Easy for experienced developers, I should think

Tags: php, paypal, path, filesystems, directory-structure

I have a website where I sell digital downloads, and have been trying to set up PayPal express checkout for some time. I am finally getting it integrated, but there is one thing that I can't figure out.

My code says get_script_uri( 'buy.php' ) );
This means that when the payment is processed, the user will be redirected to "buy.php".

```
PayPal_Digital_Goods_Configuration::return_url( get_script_uri( 'buy.php' ) );
```

However, my page that includes this code (paypalbuy.php) is in a directory called "dl/". When the payment is processed, and the user is redirected to 'buy.php', the user is redirected to 'dl/buy.php' because of the path.

How can I fix this? How can I set 'get_script_uri( 'http://google.com' ) );' and have the user redirected to a URL, instead of the file within the path.

EDIT: HERE IS my get_script_uri function:

```
    function get_script_uri( $script = 'index.php' ){
// IIS Fix
if( empty( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) )
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

// Strip off query string
$url = preg_replace( '/\?.*$/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
//$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.ltrim(dirname($url), '/').'/';
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].implode( '/', ( explode( '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], -1 ) ) ) . '/';

return $url . $script;
}
```

Comment: how do I use the actual path? sorry, I'm a noob.

Comment: @HugoCornellier: Use `PayPal_Digital_Goods_Configuration::return_url('http://google.com/buy.php');` (replace `google.com` with your domain of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at `get_script_uri()` source code I can't be sure, but from the directory structure you described, I infer that by changing `get_script_uri( 'buy.php' )` to `get_script_uri( '../buy.php' )` should give you the correct URL you're looking for: `../` means *parent directory*.

Comment: `
function get_script_uri( $script = 'index.php' ){

 // IIS Fix

 if( empty( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) )

  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];


 // Strip off query string

 $url = preg_replace( '/\?.*$/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

 //$url = 
'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.ltrim(dirname($url), '/').'/';
 $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].implode( '/', ( explode( '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], -1 ) ) ) . '/';

 return $url . $script;
}

There it is. I'm trying to redirect to a URL though.

Comment: @HugoCornellier: That's barely readable dude, post that properly formatted in your question.

Comment: @HugoCornellier: Have you tried what I suggested? It should work.